# `npm install` issues/failure with expo-cli and react-native-app

Tags: macos, react-native, expo, npm-install, yarnpkg

I really need some help with what seems to be the most basic task (setting up the expo/react-native project). I've installed the `expo-cli (v3.11.7)`, `react-native (v2.0.1)`, `watchman (v4.9.0)` and `node (v12.14.1)`. I've followed the tutorial up until the point where I need to run expo start and I get the following error:

```
Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older.
Error: node_modules directory is missing. Please run npm install in your project directory.
Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I've then run `npm install` and tried again but the same error pops up. I've removed the node_modules folder and that didn't work either.

**Update:**

When I npm install this is the error I'm seeing:

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.    
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://codeload.github.com/expo/react-native/tar.gz/sdk-36.0.0 failed, reason: write EPROTO 4521895360:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
```

I've installed `yarn (v1.21.1)` and tried installing using this with the same error:

```
warning expo > fbemitter > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz: write EPROTO 4356277696:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem. I was trying to install over my home network, which apparently has some proxy restrictions! No idea why.

Someone advised me to try again but connected to another network or my mobile hotspot. I tried this and it worked! Problem solved. So I guess for any others that may be experiencing the same problem, try connecting to another network and see if that helps.

If this fails, then I suppose looking at the proxy configuration and making changes there may help. But I wouldn't advise doing this unless you know ***exactly*** what you're doing.